# Copy and Paste Set of Data Based On Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy down data from A:Q based on the date in column A. The correct date will be in a freezed pane cell in G1 and I want to copy and paste it into the next blank row. For example:

Typing in 6/30/2023 date into cell G1 then all data with that date, lets say from A2:Q100 and pasting it into the blank row at A101.

What ive tried so far:

```
Sub Test()


Dim d As Integer


For d = "G1" To "G1"
If Cells(d).Value = Cells("A2:A1750").Value Then
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("2023").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub demo()
    With Sheets("2023")
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Range("G1").Value 
    End With
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.Offset property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

---

*Update:*

> `The correct date will be in a freezed pane cell in G1` is in your post

> `If a cell in column A equals G2` is in your comment

- The logic is confilct. Is the desired date from cell G1 or G2?

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim lastRow As Long, vDate
    Dim i As Long, iRow As Long
    With Sheets("2023")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        iRow = lastRow + 1
        vDate = .Range("G1").Value ' modify as needed
        For i = 2 To lastRow
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = vDate Then
                .Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 17).Copy .Cells(iRow, 1)
                iRow = iRow + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, the only thing is it copies down just G1's cell value into the end of column A. I was hoping to copy all rows based on Column A's value equaling G2. Hopefully that makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of `all rows`. If a cell in column A equals G2, then copy what?

Comment: so G2 is the date 6/30/2023, the each row has data starting with the date in column A for example each month end, so 5/31/2023, 6/30/3023 etc. I want to copy down the data for the whole row in the next blank cell based on the value in G2. So each row has data until column Q: for example price in column M and product name in column B.

Comment: Please share a screenshot about current data layout (table) and expected result in your post. It is helpful to revise code to meet your requirement.

Comment: just shared it - thanks

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: This works thanks so much! my bad that was a typo it was G1